# XMPPFramework - How to get offline user profile status

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I want to get offline user (friend) status:

My code is working fine when user is online, so i am getting user status but when he goes offline `user.primaryResource.presence.status` gives `nil` value.

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Status: %@",user.primaryResource.presence.status);
```

After user goes offline i check the `XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject` table for particular `jidStr` its give me zero objects means when user goes offline its remove the ResourcesObject of that user.

So, there is any possibility to get a status of that user.

Comment: By status you mean, the user ins `Online` or `Offline` ? If yes then if the `presense` give you nil doesn't it mean user is is `Offline` ?

Comment: Status means presence status which is save in XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject -> object -> primaryResource  so, when user goes offline XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject object becomes nil.

Comment: Have you try XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage?

Comment: @dichen Yes, i have also try XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage function:
 - (XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)userForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid
                                   xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)stream
                         managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
but it also return nil value when user goes offline.

Answer (score 0):

You check the source code of `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject`

```
- (void)updateWithPresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence streamBareJidStr:(NSString *)streamBareJidStr
{
    XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *resource =
        (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *)[self resourceForJID:[presence from]];

    if ([[presence type] isEqualToString:@"unavailable"] || [presence isErrorPresence])
    {
        if (resource)
        {
            [self removeResourcesObject:resource];
            [[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:resource];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (resource)
        {
            [resource updateWithPresence:presence];
        }
        else
        {
            XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *newResource;
            newResource = [XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject insertInManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]
                                                                       withPresence:presence
                                                                   streamBareJidStr:streamBareJidStr];

            [self addResourcesObject:newResource];
        }
    }

    [self recalculatePrimaryResource];
}
```

You can see the `resource` will be removed if offline.

For myself, I check `user.primaryResource?.presence?.type() == "available"` as `online`, other cases as `offline`.  (Assume **user** is the `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject` you got from db)